# SQL delete type double

Tags: sql, prepared-statement, sql-delete

I am having some issue with sql... Below have a working and not working example. I hard coded them so its easier to see.

```
$deleteData = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM markers WHERE sid=? AND user_id=? AND lat=? AND lng=?");
$deleteData->bind_param("iidd", $sid, $user_id,$lat,$lng);  

$sid= '239';
$user_id = '2';
$lat = '39.724869';
$lng = '-91.400116';

$deleteData -> execute();
```

Some reason when I attempt to delete using type double in bind_param just doesn't work. Any suggestions? I changed it with or without '' around the lat lng, still doesn't work.

If I change it to below, it deletes just fine.

```
$deleteData = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM markers WHERE sid=? AND user_id=?);
$deleteData->bind_param("ii", $sid, $user_id);  

$sid= '239';
$user_id = '2';

$deleteData -> execute();
```

Comment: By "doesn't work", I assume you mean you don't get an error, but neither does the record you expected to be deleted actually get deleted. Is that accurate?

Comment: Yeah. No error and nothing deleted...

Comment: which RDBMS? Might be connected to your system's culture. Some cultures expect the comma as decimal delimiter. And a silly question: Are you really sure that there is data which fits to all 4 parameters?

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks for looking into it. It was strangely affect by tolerance (selected as answer) when I compared against two identical value.. but it worked.

Comment: @SQLNub, glad you could solve this. Dealing with floats can be tricky :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have a syntax error in the second example (missing character ").

Also you did not assigned `$sid` variable.

Then I have a little bit stupid question. Are you aware, that assign of variables `$blog_id, $user_id ...` etc. must be before call of method `$deleteData->bind_param()`?

And also, don't forget that when you are comparing 2 real values, then you should also add some tolerance, so try instead:

```
$deleteData = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM markers WHERE sid=? AND user_id=? AND ABS(lat - ?) < 0.0000001 AND ABS(lng - ?) < 0.0000001");
```

Comment: My mistake on the $sid part. I changed some variables before posting. The tolerance got it! Even with the same value, not sure why it wasn't registering. Thank you!

Comment: Computer works with real (floating) numbers in a binary form, which is only 32 or 64 bit long. Due to this, real numbers can be stored with little variation.

Eg. number 39.724869  can be for example actually stored as 39.7248690000001.

So when you are comparing two real numbers you should always also add some tolerance.

Moreover, you are working with 2 separate systems PHP & MySQL and both of them can work with real numbers in a different way. For example in PHP can be real number stored in 64bit format and in MySQL you have defined columns `lat` & `lng` as 32bit numbers.

Comment: Great explanation. Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$blog_id = '239';`with `$sid = '239';` since that's the variable name you use in the bind_param() statement.

Comment: That was a mistake. I forgot to edit that to show the actual issue. Thanks for catching it.